# Can't get Google's Search API to work with Python

Tags: python, google-search-api

I'm using google's own search API but I keep getting a 403 error. The key is taken from console.developers.google.com under APIs & auth -> Credentials and I used a Browser key with any referrers. The ID is taken from under the custom search engines basic information.

```
import requests

search = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1"
key = "?key=MY_KEY"
id_ = "&cx=MY_ID"
query = "&q=test"

get = search + key + id_ + query

r = requests.get(get)

print(r)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: perhaps [urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)

Comment: Have you checked the URL to see exactly what it looks like when it executes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the source of your problem or not, but you could be making much better use of the `requests` library.  For starters, you can put your API key and CX value into a session object, where they can be used in subsequent requests:

```
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> s.params['key'] = 'MY_KEY'
>>> s.params['cx'] = 'MY_CX'
```

And you can pass additional search parameters by passing a dict in the `params` keyword, rather than building the URL yourself:

```
>>> result = s.get('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1', 
... params={'q': 'my search string'})
```

This all works for me:

```
>>> result
<Response [200]>
>>> print result.text
{
 "kind": "customsearch#search",
 "url": {
  "type": "application/json",
  "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe
[...]
```

Also, it's worth checking that you have [enabled the search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/introduction#identify_your_application_to_google_with_api_key) for your API key.

You can see exactly what the `requests` library is doing by enabling debug logging through the Python `logging` module:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
>>> result = s.get('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1', params={'q': 'openstack'})
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /customsearch/v1?q=openstack&cx=0123456789123456789%3Aabcdefghijk&key=THIS_IS_MY_KEY HTTP/1.1" 200 13416
```